# Is it possible to publish TFS 2010 Builds to IIS 6?

Tags: iis-6, tfsbuild

Before I spend too much time trying to make this work, I would like to know if it's even possible.  I can build the projects fine using TFS.  I can also publish directly from Visual Studio without issue.  But when trying to publish via TFS, it is trying to use the following url:  https://dev.server.com:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=dev.server.com.  It is my understanding that port 8172 is the Windows Management Service, which I do not belive runs with IIS6.  Is there any way to publish the applications using port 80,  the same url that I supply manually withing visual studio?

Thx

Comment: It looks like you're using msdeploy to publish the site.  I haven't really played with it but from memory msdeploy only has limited IIS6 support.  Does it work when you try publishing manually?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following settings ni build definition of TFS, and it should work:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
/p:DeployIISAppPath="test deploy" 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=http://deployserver/MsDeployAgentService 
/p:UserName=username
/p:Password=xxxxx 
/p:IncludeIisSettingsOnPublish=false
```

The clue is to set **IncludeIisSettingsOnPublish=false**